# Async data to child page with Ionic5

Tags: asynchronous, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I'm trying to pass data between a parent and a child page in ionic using Ionic Storage to get the data in an async way.

What is happening is that when I get to the page, the data didn't return from the storage yet and I have an undefined error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

What I am using:

- A parent page that I click in an item in the grid and it forwards me to the child page, using router.navigate

```
  goToMediaDetails(data) {
    this.router.navigate([`slate-list/${data.id}`]);
  }
```

- The child route is listed in the app-routing.module.ts receiving the id

```
  {
    path: "slate-list/:mediaId",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./pages/slate-list/slate-list.module").then(
        m => m.SlateListPageModule
      )
  }
```

- I grab the mediaId in the child's constructor page and use a service to get the data from ionic storage.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

//Services
import { MediaService } from "../../services/media.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-slate-list",
  templateUrl: "./slate-list.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./slate-list.page.scss"]
})
export class SlateListPage implements OnInit {
  public media: any;
  private mediaId: number;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private mediaSvc: MediaService
  ) {
    //if the id is provided in the url, get the media by id using the service
    if (route.snapshot.params.mediaId) {
      this.mediaId = route.snapshot.params.mediaId;
      this.mediaSvc.getMediaById(this.mediaId).then(result => {
        this.media = result;
      });
    }
  }
```

- Here is the service code returning a promise

```
  //GET Media By ID
  getMediaById(mediaId) {
    let mediaToReturn = new Media();
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.storage.get("media").then(result => {
        if (result != null && result.length != 0) {
          mediaToReturn = result.find(x => x.id == mediaId);
        }

        resolve(mediaToReturn);
      });
    });
  }
```

- Here is the simple html giving the problem

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid class="ion-no-padding">
    <ion-row>
      Slates for <strong>{{media.name}} </strong> / Episode: {{media.episode}}
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Yes, the data is returned using the service, I console.log it right after the .then and the data is there, so I'm assuming that it's just a classic async situation.

I saw I can introduce a loading component, make it show up for 1 second or a bit more and then the data will be there but is that the better/official way to do it?

I'm at the beginning of my journey with ionic/async so forgive me if I made some silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

ts file:

```
public media: any = {}
```

html:

```
Slates for <strong>{{media?.name}} </strong> / Episode: {{media?.episode}}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, even without the = {} on the media.
I did not know about this? operator. I'll try to search for it, I got curious how it works.